# Call outlook VBA from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2007, outlook-2007

I have a function in the outlook VBA that I want to call when a certain excel workbook is closed. Is there a way to do this with the BeforeClose event of excel? I know how to write functions for this event, but I am not sure how to link them to the current outlook session to get to the function.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to get hold of a reference to an *instance* of Outlook that is already running, you will need to use:

```
Set myOutlookApp = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")
```

which will give you access to the Outlook application object so you can call your desired VBA function in Outlook:

```
myOutlookApp.MyFunctionToExecute()
```

You'll probably need to make the function `Public` otherwise Excel's VBA might not be able to see it.

Comment: I believe the function has to be public and it must be in ThisOutlookSession for this method to work.

Comment: Appears `myOutlookApp.MyFunctionToExecute()` is not valid. Bring the code into Excel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893262/vba-call-outlook-macro-from-excel-object-does-not-support-property-or-method and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121335/run-a-macro-in-outlook-from-excel

Answer (score 3):

MS Office applications can interact with each other by this method (this is based on Office 2007, but others will be similar):

Add a reference to the app into Excel

In Excel VBA, from the Tools\References menu select Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library

In your BeforeClose Event include

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
```

You can now access Outlook through the olApp object. I don't know much about the Outlook object model, so others may be able help more from here on...