# Open Outlook Macro With Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call outlook VBA from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096353/call-outlook-vba-from-excel)

I know about the `Application.Run` method from Excel, with which I can open an Excel macro from Outlook.

I need to switch the `Excel.Application` object to `Outlook.Application` and it doesn't work.

The error message is: `"Method is not supported."`

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.outlook.program_vba/cQ8gF9ssN3g), the only way to do this is to call a procedure stored in `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
myOlApp.MyProcedure
```

However, this seems unsupported by MS.