# Run Outlook VBA Code from R

Tags: r, vba, outlook

I am aware of a potential shell/vbs script solution. 
However, I am seeking a solution with the `library(RDCOMClient)` package.

I looked into:

- [Run VBA script from R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404270/run-vba-script-from-r)
- [Call outlook VBA from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096353/call-outlook-vba-from-excel)

Some attempts from me (given a `Public Sub dss()` in `ThisOutlookSession`) in Outlook:

```
library(RDCOMClient)
> OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
> oa<-OutApp[["Session"]][["Accounts"]]
> OutApp$dss()
Error in .COM(x, name, ...) : 
  Cannot locate 0 name(s) dss in COM object (status = -2147352570)
> OutApp$Application$dss()
Error in OutApp$Application$dss : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> OutApp$Run("dss")
Error in .COM(x, name, ...) : 
  Cannot locate 0 name(s) Run in COM object (status = -2147352570)
```

Macro could be simply:

```
Public Sub dss()
    Dim excApp As Object
    Dim excWkb As Object
    Dim excWks As Object

    Set excApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set excWkb = excApp.Workbooks.Add()

    excWkb.SaveAs "AXX.xlsx"
    excWkb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You can not call Outlook vba from Excel or any other Application

Comment: According to the second link i provided, it is possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096353/call-outlook-vba-from-excel

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I am not sure I understand you correctly: I face the same challenge as posted above und was not able to run an outlook macro from R via RDCOMClient. Attempts listed above also didnt work for me,...

Comment: @TarunLalwani. Ah i get it. I made an edit!

Comment: There isn't a `Visible` property of the Outlook.Application object. Is that your question?

Comment: @BigDataScientist, please also update the Outlook version you are using

Comment: For me it is Outlook 2016; @RyanWildry: Visible property is not relevant for me. I just want to trigger that an outlook macro is triggered from R via RDCOMClient.

Comment: @BigDataScientist I'd be interesting seeing some documentation on that. Also, your question is really unclear on what your expected outcome is. Consider revising it.

Answer (score 3):

### Two ways

#### 1. In Outlook Application

Outlook.Application does not have a visible property, see this post -> http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-8287.html
You will use a folder or mail item Display method to show outlook
To display the outlook window add below code to your 'dss' macro
`ThisOutlookSession.ActiveExplorer.Display`

Also you will need to put your public 'dss' macro inside outlook ThisOutLookSession to be able to call it out of outlook.

Then try your R code this way

```
    library(RDCOMClient)
    OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
    OutApp$Run("dss")
```

#### 2. In Excel Application

If your macro is simply to create an Excel workbook why are you doing it in Outlook.Application use Excel.Application.
Create an excel workbook with the macro in a module, and execute as below

```
    library(RDCOMClient)
    #Open a specific workbook in Excel:
    xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
    xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open("C:\\Temp\\macro_template.xlsm")

    # this line of code might be necessary if you want to see your spreadsheet:
    xlApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE 

    # Run the macro called "dss":
    xlApp$Run("dss")

    # Close the workbook and quit the app:
    xlWbk$Close(FALSE)
    xlApp$Quit()`
```

Above is slight modified code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43222477/5871610

Comment: hmm,...first of all thanks for your effort. 1) Running: `OutApp$Run("dss")` returns
`Error in .COM(x, name, ...) : 
  Cannot locate 0 name(s) Run in COM object (status = -2147352570) ` as described in the question. Macro is placed as described in "ThisOutlook..." and runs properly if called in outlook. The macro itself is just an example. Reproducing it in R would not be the question at hand. Thank you!

Comment: `os<-OutApp$Session$dss()` 
Try execute the procedure against the `Outlook.Application.Session` as above.

Comment: that returns: `Error in OutApp$Session$dss : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Does that code work for you?

Answer (score 3):

> As far as I can tell, it's not possible to run macros that are stored in Outlook from other applications. Outlook lacks the Application.Run method that is available in Word and Excel.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5a6396c4-ad24-42a4-b711-101e24254334/how-to-fire-outlook-macro-through-excel-vba?forum=exceldev

So leave R out of the question here, I can assure you can't even execute this from the Outlook macro editor itself, starting with the top level Application object

I have tried every combination I could think of with the outlook macro and I am afraid this not possible now. It may have been in older version of outlook like 2007 or so but not now

[image: Not working]

If you can get this working in VBScript or outlook, it will work in `R` as well. But I am afraid you can't make it working anywhere

The possible workaround that you could do may be

- Define a rule with a trigger point and associate the macro with the same. Try to simulate the trigger instead of calling macro directly.
- Create a custom button in toolbar and see if it is possible to invoke the command from external vba (this will be really tough to crack)