# Execute VBA Outlook Macro from Powershell or C# Console app

Tags: c#, vba, powershell, outlook

I have made an VBA Macro which gets all the events from an Outlook calendar and writes them to an excel file.

I then need to execute this macro from either a powershell script, or an C# console app.

Is there any way to do this?

Im on win10 using Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook's `Application` class doesn't have a `Run` member, and makes it extremely hard to invoke VBA code out-of-process (heck, even in-process), presumably for security reasons. When [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) initially implemented unit testing support for Outlook VBA, it was a literal [hackjob](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/v2.1.0/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/Application/OutlookApp.cs) involving creating a commandbar button and assigning its "OnAction" to the unit test procedure we wanted to invoke - like this:

```
var app = Application;
var exp = app.ActiveExplorer();
CommandBar cb = exp.CommandBars.Add("RubberduckCallbackProxy", Temporary: true);
CommandBarControl btn = cb.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 1);
btn.OnAction = declaration.QualifiedName.ToString();
btn.Execute();
cb.Delete();
```

So if you make `btn.OnAction = "YourMacro";` and have a reference to the Outlook interop assembly (`Application` is `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application`), I believe this can work - the macro must be in a standard module though - if it's in `ThisOutlookSession` then the wheels come off.

(note, since then we've figured out a much more elegant, host-agnostic way to run the user's test methods, but that wouldn't work out-of-process)

The `ThisOutlookSession` object is extended at run-time with the public members of that class, so if your macro is written in `ThisOutlookSession` then [from VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111740/1188513) you can invoke it like `app.MacroName`, but we haven't been able to [get that to work from C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31954364/1188513).

Lastly, note that the above code will be leaking COM objects. Make sure you clean up unmanaged objects properly, otherwise you'll see a ghost OUTLOOK.EXE process lingering in the *task manager* waiting to be killed, well afer your script/console app is gone.