# VBA: Call Outlook Macro From Excel. Object Does not support property or method

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to call a public macro stored in ThisOutlookSession from an excel macro. The outlook is open at all times.

I found the following:
[Call outlook VBA from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096353/call-outlook-vba-from-excel)

My excel code:

```
Set myOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Not myOutlookApp Is Nothing Then myOutlookApp.ReadEmails
```

On the second line i get an error:

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried making the subroutine 'ReadMails' public?

Comment: @bub yes i mentioned above that it's public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access Outlook macros using syntax like `Application.YourFunctionName`. You will need to convert your Outlook VBA code to an Excel VBA script.